# Facebook share on a Facebook Page timeline, on behalf of the user

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine, facebook-javascript-sdk

On a mobile app, I want to have a Share button that posts an image on behalf of the user, but instead of posting it on this user's timeline, it must be posted on a specific Facebook Page timeline.

By using the Share dialog, it seems there is no way to configure the target of the post (in this case, the Facebook Page). Or at least I couldn't find it.

How would you do it?

Note: the app is made in Unity/C#, although I don't think this would matter much

Comment: That is currently not possible using any of the dialogs. You would need to create an app, have users login to it and grant it publishing permission, and then make the post via API.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :)

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {               
        FB.init({
            appId      : '**appId**',
            channelUrl : '//local.facebook-test/channel.html',
            status     : true,
            xfbml      : true,
            oauth      : true
        });
        FB.login(function(response)
        {
            if (response.authResponse)
            {                    
                 var opts = {
                    message : '**message**',
                    access_token: '**PageAccessToken**',
                    name : '**name**',
                    link : 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
                    description : '**description**',
                    picture : 'http://url/to/pic.jpg'                                                        
                 };
                FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', opts, function(response)
                 {
                    if (!response || response.error)
                    {
                        console.log(response.error);
                        alert('Posting error occured');
                    }else{
                        alert('Success - Post ID: ' + response.id);
                    }
                 });
            } else {
                alert('Not logged in');
            }
        }, { scope: 'manage_pages, publish_actions, user_photos' });

    };
    (function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```